# Django ORM with Rest API writing complex query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I wrote a functionality like if a person have related data, user can't perform update.

Here you go for my models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    alias = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Appointment(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="patient_for_appointment", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Sales(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="customer_for_sales", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.FloatField()

class Prescription(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="Patient_for_prescription", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

My primary key is `UUID` named `alias`

this is my api view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import Person, Appointment, Prescription, Sales
from . serializers import  PersonSerializers
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException

class PersonView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializers
    lookup_field = 'alias'

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # person = Person.objects.filter(alias=kwargs['alias'])
        appointment = Appointment.objects.filter(patient__alias=kwargs['alias'])
        prescription = Prescription.objects.filter(patient__alias=kwargs['alias'])
        sales = Sales.objects.filter(customer__alias=kwargs['alias'])

        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if prescription:
            raise APIException('CANT UPDATE')
        elif appointment:
            raise APIException('CANT UPDATE')
        elif sales:
            raise APIException('CANT UPDATE')
        else:         
            self.perform_update(serializer)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Look closely above view some query:

```
        appointment = Appointment.objects.filter(patient__alias=kwargs['alias'])
        prescription = Prescription.objects.filter(patient__alias=kwargs['alias'])
        sales = Sales.objects.filter(customer__alias=kwargs['alias'])
```

I implement here if a Person have `sales` or `appointment` or `prescription`, user can't to perform update and throw an error. Everything is working fine

But i have an performance issue with query, i am trying to make a single query/filter with a person primary key to get the person `Appointment` and `Sales` and `Prescription`.

Above thing working fine but i am trying to make a single query in person like below:

```
person = Person.objects.filter(alias='a person alias/primary key).prefetch_related..............
```

But i failed to achieve it. Can anyone help me to achieve filter my `Person` model only to get its Appointment, Sales, and Prescription?

I am exhausted on trying on it and just got stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your in the following way:

```
      person=Person.objects.filter(alias=kwargs.get('alias').values("Patient_for_prescription", "patient_for_appointment", "customer_for_sales" , "name", "alias")
```

All the person data and related appointments, sales and prescriptions will be listed using this query.

The queryset might contain multiple rows depending upon data in db. To avoid that you can use `.first()` or `.last()` or `where` condition with your query to get a single person object for your view because your view expects a single object.

Comment: It throws me an error  django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'patient_for_prescription' into field. Choices are: Patient_for_prescription, alias, customer_for_sales, name, patient_for_appointment

Comment: Just wanted to confirm : you have a capital P in `Patient_for_prescription`, are you using small p for the same in the query ? Because that might be causing the error.